# Installing GNU-Parallel: How to enter "will cite" from docker build?

Tags: docker, gnu-parallel

In the docker file:

```
from debian:latest

RUN apt-get install parallel
RUN parallel --citation <<< "will cite"
```

And the docker build simply does not complete because of this entry process. How to install parallel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
RUN yes 'will cite' | parallel --citation
```

Is one possible answer.

---

For a history on **GNU-parallel** (and original script):

[GNU Parallel since 2001](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/history.html)

It appears that recent devs introduced this 'will cite' viral-marketing concept. I guess it isn't as bad as naming a then-2000 year old math equation after oneself (sorry Pythagoras), but it is annoying when spinning up images in a commercial context.

If it continues to be a problem on your images, consider setting up a **makefile** or running the original **parallel** code (see link above).

---

I have also never gotten **parallel** to work on multiple computers -- TLDR -> Too Complicated, Never Tried -- and may instead look into **pexec**:

[**pxec**: execute command in parallel on remote machines](https://www.gnu.org/software/pexec/pexec.1.html)

This would be the map operation in a unix-style MAP->REDUCE implementation. On the remote box, **make** or **GNU-parallel** could still be used.

Comment: This seems to cause a loop with `GNU parallel 20211122` since the program just keeps asking for citation.

Comment: @mhvelplund good catch. This whole "will cite" thing is an annoying new development for "GNU" `parallel`, which I was using for the first time in an air-gapped context back in 2008.  I guess it has been around since 2001, but has been developed significantly in the last few years. If you find a new and better way to get rid of it, great.

Answer (score 3):

For version `GNU parallel 20211122` I had to change @Chris' answer to:

```
RUN echo 'will cite' | parallel --citation || true
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on GNU parallel version 2022102:

```
touch ~/.parallel/will-cite
```

For example, running in a Fedora 37 docker:

```
[root@4b60c99bec99 ~]# parallel echo {} ::: 1 2 3
Academic tradition requires you to cite works you base your article on
...
To silence this citation notice: run 'parallel --citation' once.

1
2
3
[root@4b60c99bec99 ~]# touch ~/.parallel/will-cite
[root@4b60c99bec99 ~]# parallel echo {} ::: 1 2 3
1
2
3
[root@4b60c99bec99 ~]#
```